# fortran segmentation fault occured in the process of a loop

Tags: loops, segmentation-fault, fortran

I wrote a code with its main structure being as follows

```
program main
   use modules ...
   implicit none

do i = 1, N_trials
  call some_function()
end do

end program main
```

inside the loop, `some_function` is called and they are independent between different step `i`. There is no `segmentation fault` when I compile these source files and no problem about stack size because I set `ulimit -s` to `unlimited`. However, segmentation fault occurs in the process of the loop and it seems to be random. For example, sometimes it happened when `i` becomes 3 but sometimes when `i` becomes 5 or other number. The output before `segmentation fault` happened is normal. I wonder why and some suggestions about how to locate/identify such error.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I'd include run time checks and detailed stack traces, for example with the Intel Fortran Compiler that'd be `-check all -warn all -g -O0 -traceback`. But those flags differ between compilers.

Comment: The real `some_function` could be helpful...

Comment: Please read [ask] and  [mcve]. We need to see the code, not just a small piece of it. The function or subroutine is necessary. Show us a compilable code, compile it with all warnings and checks (`-g -Wall -fcheck=all`) and show us the output.

Comment: Try using `gdb` and/or `valgrind --tool=memcheck` to debug.